# selecting data from one mysql table and insert into another table

Tags: php

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    mysql_select_db("inventory");
    $data=mysql_query("SELECT product_name, cp FROM product WHERE qty=0");
    $rec=mysql_fetch_row($data);

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO outofstock (product_name, quantity) VALUES ('$rec['product_name']', '$rec['qty']')"))
    {
        echo "Added";
    }

?>
```

when i run this i get this error->

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\outofstock.php on line 8

Comment: mysql_* is now deprecated you should learn either mysqli or pdo.

Comment: can be done in one `INSERT INTO outofstock  SELECT product_name, cp as quantity FROM product WHERE qty=0`

Comment: And the error comes from `'$rec['product_name']'` change it to `'{$rec['product_name']}'` and on all other variables

Comment: but it is fetching values from table product but problem is in second query i guess

Comment: it worked thank you so much..:)